# 10x Genomics Chromium single-cell RNA-seq data analysis options?

Tags: rna-seq, r, bioconductor, scrnaseq, 10x-genomics

Provide an overview of 10x data analysis packages.

10x provides Cell Ranger which prepares a count matrix from the bcl sequencer output files and other files (see bottom of page https://support.10xgenomics.com/docs/license for the programs it uses).

What can we do with the output files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Data preparation

Cell Ranger uses the Illumina sequencing output (`.bcl`) files

1. [Make fastq files](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/mkfastq):
   `cellranger mkfastq` ==> `.fastq`
2. Prepare count matrix: `cellranger count` ==> `matrix.mtx, web_summary.html, cloupe.cloupe`
3. Optional: combine multiple `matrix.mtx` files (libraries): `cellranger aggr`

---

## Data analysis

**[Loupe Cell Browser](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/visualization/latest/what-is-loupe-cell-browser) visualization of** `cloupe.cloupe` **files**

**Count table** `matrix.mtx` **analysis options:**

- [`Python`](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/python)
- `R` [Cell Ranger R Kit](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/rkit): `cellrangerRkit::load_cellranger_matrix()` ==> ExpressionSet
- `R` [Scater](http://hemberg-lab.github.io/scRNA.seq.course/scater-package.html): `scater::read10XResults()` ==> SCESet object
- `R` [Seurat](http://satijalab.org/seurat/pbmc-tutorial.html): `Seurat::Read10X()` ==> Seurat object